# Convert zeplin style guide export files to language agnostic format?

Tags: c#, objective-c, xamarin, zeplin

Zeplin has a style guide which you can export as essentially a look up dictionary in Swift or Objective C, it ends up looking like this;

```
    @implementation UIColor (OLAdditions)

+ (UIColor *)ipd_goldenYellowColor { 
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:250.0f / 255.0f green:206.0f / 255.0f blue:21.0f / 255.0f alpha:1.0f];
}

@end

// Text styles

@implementation UIFont (OLAdditions)

+ (UIFont *)ipd_titleBigH1WhiteFont {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@".SFNSDisplay-Regular" size:58.0f];
}


+ (UIFont *)ipd_smallWhite60Font {
    return [UIFont fontWithName:@".SFNSDisplay-Regular" size:12.0f];
}

@end
```

I'm trying to figure out how to use these objective-c/swift files in my xamarin project which uses C#, I was thinking if there was a way to convert these files into xml I could read them in through C#, is there an easy way to do this or abetter solution to my problem?